# how to merge two dataframes in pandas based on order

Tags: python, pandas

I have two df's that I want to merge but they do not have a common column.

Thus, I have created a temporary column on each of the dataframes called `tmp`:

```
y_pred['tmp'] = 1
data['tmp'] = 1
```

`data` looks like:

```
     mean  year  tmp
4600  2.3  2019  1
2601  5.3  2020  1
```

whereas `y_pred` looks like:

```
     pred_score  tmp
0     2           1
1     5.2         1
```

and I merge them:

```
new_df = pd.merge(data, y_pred, on=['tmp'], how='left')
new_df.drop('tmp', inplace=True, axis=1)
```

I get 900 rows where I need to have only 30 (suppose that datasets have 30 rows each, I get 30 times 30)

whereas what I need is `new_df` to have 30 rows and just merge the column `pred_score` to `data` in the order the rows are currently.

So that I would get:

new_df:

```
     mean  year  pred_score
4600  2.3  2019  2
2601  5.3  2020  5.2
```

Is there a way to achieve this without having a common column?

Comment: looks like just `data.reset_index(drop=True).join(y_pred)`.

Comment: yes, that worked actually. Thanks a lot. You may want to add it as an answer, and I can make it as solved.

Comment: You don't need to `reset_index` and `join`. Just create a new column.

Comment: both solutions work. But just creating a new column seems to be better I think, without resetting the index. Thanks a lot both of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `y_pred.values`:

```
>>> data
      mean  year
4600   2.3  2019
2601   5.3  2020

>>> y_pred
   pred_score
0         2.0
1         5.2

>>> data['pred_score'] = y_pred.values

# Output
      mean  year  pred_score
4600   2.3  2019         2.0
2601   5.3  2020         5.2
```